# iOS push notification and distribute the application inhouse

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I just want to make an iOS mobile application for my in house company use. I am very new to iOS. Just studying. I got some doubts

1. Is it necessary to buy iOS developer account for developing such an application. From readings I found that its necessary.
2. Got a push notification in my application. So Can I develop and test the push notification with out purchasing the developer license ?

I know these are beginners question. But when I googled I found that someone's saying about the provision certificate making and make application with uid and all. Just confused.

Please any one give me a little idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the solution of your both answers.you have to enrol for developer program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to buy developer license for creating any application.

Below are few things which are not possible without purchasing developer license, and which are compulsory.

1. Create certificate
2. Create Application ID
3. Add device identifier for AdHoc development (Testing)
4. Create Provisioning Profiles

So without developer account you won't be able to test your code as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya thanks... Planning to purchase that $99 account. Is it enough ?

Comment: Assuming your plan is to develop only for in house individual account would be enough otherwise you need to enroll for enterprise account if you wish to develop on large scale for in house projects.

Comment: No.. Its for in house only. Purpose is we will develop the app and upload in our corporate server. All employees can download that application and install from our server at anytime. Is this possible ?

Comment: For that you need to enroll for enterprise account which is 299$ I guess.

Comment: Ok if I purchase $99 account, then I need to release my application via iStore is it ?

Comment: Yes you can do it like add some authentication mechanism specific to your organization and keep application free so only employes of your organization can authorize and access the application. In that way you can reduce cost of the enrollment.